# How to change parameter value for SSRS report subscription

Tags: reporting-services

Probably something that has been anwered before. But I have not used SSRS and probably not understanding a probable solution.

I have a SSRS report subscription that delivers the report to a specific folder. This works fine.
The report has two parameters - one mandatory and the other optional.
When creating the subscription, I have supplied a default value (booking id) for the mandatory parameter.
The report itself is a delivery note which has to be generated when an order is ready to shipped.
As you can imagine the booking id will vary for each delivery note.
Based on some prior processing I need to update the booking id before call the subscription job.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Hope my question is clear

I have searched around but not found a direct solution for this.
Or there might be one that probably needs expanding on but I am not sure how I would do this.